# How to calculate pixel area of an image in Lambda from an S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to calculate the pixel area of images uploaded to a bucket in S3. So far, I have managed to put a trigger on my Lambda function in response to an image upload in S3, I have also managed to add all the necessary libraries.

To read the image loaded into the bucket I used the `key` inside `cv2.imread()`, but in doing so I got a path integrity warning.

**warning**

```
[ WARN:0@0.470] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp
(239) findDecoder imread_('public/IMG-10.jpg'):
can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
```

**lambda_function.py**

```
import boto3
import base64
import numpy as np
import cv2

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)


    # getting bucket and object key from event object
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    # taking image from bucket to calculate pixel area
    image = cv2.imread(key)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    total = 0

    for c in cnts:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [c], [255,255,255])
        mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        pixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
        total += pixels
        cv2.putText(image, '{}'.format(pixels), (x,y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 2)

    print(total)
```

My problem is how to correctly access the image path to be read via opencv.

Comment: Your question is not clear, at least to me. Lambda looks fine but what does applying a classification model mean? How are you doing that and where? What does its input require?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have a machine learning model that tells me if my image is a goat or not. In order to be able to classify the image that is uploaded I need to have access to its path. My doubt is how to get access to this path through of the image.

Comment: The image doesn't have a path to the local filesystem at this point.  If you want one, you could write it to disk (to the /tmp folder).

Comment: Is there any way to access the image that triggers my `Lambda` function, without using its path?

Comment: @DiegoA - when s3 triggers your lambda, it passes information about the path (s3 key). You already have that. Which path you are referring to? If you mean the source path, I would recommend tagging the image so it carries that information for you to pull from metadata

Comment: @AdilHindistan I tried to use s3 key as your suggestion, but I couldn't open/read the image due to path/integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's need to first establish a connection to S3, then download the image data, and finally decode the data with OpenCV.

Full sample code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import boto3
import base64
import numpy as np
import cv2


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

    # getting bucket and object key from event object
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    img_file = BytesIO()
    s3_client.download_fileobj(source_bucket, key, img_file)
        
    
    np_1d_array = np.frombuffer(img_file.getbuffer(), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(np_1d_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    total = 0

    for c in cnts:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [c], [255,255,255])
        mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        pixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
        total += pixels
        cv2.putText(image, '{}'.format(pixels), (x,y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 2)

    print("ÁREA EM PIXEL:", total)
```